# how can I create InternetGateway with Pulumi

Tags: pulumi

I have a problem that I can't create InternetGateway with pulumi when execute pulumi up.

even if I execute pulumi up, the Execution result will be above sentence.
my ideal is （read） → （create）.

code is following.

```
const vpc = new aws.ec2.Vpc("custom1-vpc", {
            cidrBlock: "10.51.0.0/16",
            enableDnsHostnames: true,
            enableClassiclinkDnsSupport: true,
            instanceTenancy: "default",
            tags: {
                Name: "custom1-vpc"
            }
        });

const internatGateway = new aws.ec2.InternetGateway("custom1_gateway", {
            vpcId: vpc.id
        }, vpc);
```

result is following.

```
Do you want to perform this update? details
+ pulumi:pulumi:Stack: (create)
    [urn=urn:pulumi:pulumi-with-typescript::typescriptPulumi::pulumi:pulumi:Stack::typescriptPulumi-pulumi-with-typescript]
    + aws:ec2/vpc:Vpc: (create)
        [urn=urn:pulumi:pulumi-with-typescript::typescriptPulumi::aws:ec2/vpc:Vpc::custom1-vpc]
        assignGeneratedIpv6CidrBlock: false
        cidrBlock                   : "10.51.0.0/16"
        enableClassiclinkDnsSupport : true
        enableDnsHostnames          : true
        enableDnsSupport            : true
        instanceTenancy             : "default"
        tags                        : {
            Name      : "custom1-vpc"
        }
    > aws:ec2/internetGateway:InternetGateway: (read)
        [urn=urn:pulumi:pulumi-with-typescript::typescriptPulumi::aws:ec2/internetGateway:InternetGateway::custom1_gateway]
        vpcId: output<string>
```

Comment: I've switched to the CrossWalk lib (awsx) this will create the Internet Gateway for you when creating a vpc e.g. `this.vpc = new awsx.ec2.Vpc(name)` - It's possible to override any of the props by passing in a second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't specify `vpc` as the third parameter. Just run this:

```js
const internatGateway = new aws.ec2.InternetGateway("custom1_gateway", {
     vpcId: vpc.id
});
```